# customizing size of an iframe within a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, joomla1.5

i am displaying a remote webpage on my site like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.smopething.com/index.cfm"

frameborder="0"
width="800"
scrolling="no"
height="1100">

</iframe>
```

is it possible for me to customize the size of it? something like `<iframe src="etc", height=something,width=something>` ???

Comment: I don't understand the question; the iframe source you posted has width and height attributes, why not just change those?

Comment: mark it doesnt fit for soem reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS if you like:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" style="width:640px;height:480px;"></iframe>
```

Or you could use the width and height attributes:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: That markup isn't actually incorrect; the end tag is there so that you can enclose content for browsers that don't support iframes. The style tag will still work whether you self-close the tag or not.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working i did as you say and it is not not appearing correctly sized look http://www.yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=8&Itemid=34

Comment: @OP Make sure nothing is overwriting the styles/rules you're declaring.

Answer (score 2):

The best ways are:

For just height/width, IFRAME has height/width attributes, as seen [in W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/frames.html#h-16.5).

For more control, enclose the `iframe` into a `DIV` element and then style the size of the DIV with CSS
(it may work if you apply CSS directly to the IFRAME but I am not 100% certain of that)

Comment: Just add `width="800" height="1100"` to your IFRAME element attributes as you did

Comment: im not sure i understand since that code is already in the question